# How to Bind a command of child class object declared in Main context ViewMOdel xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having a page(MyPage) and Corresponding view Model(MypageViewModel). I have another view model called(listItemLogicVM) and its declared as observable collection in MypageViewModel.

**MyPage XAML**

```
  <ListView x:Name="lstvwItemSelected" ItemsSource="{Binding 
     LstlistItemLogicVM}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                       <ViewCell >
                         <StackLayout>
                            <Entry Text="{Binding RequestingQty,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                             <Image Source="ArrowUp.png"><Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding QtyDecrementCommand}"/>
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                             </Image>
                         </StackLayout>
                       </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```

**MypageViewModel**

```
  public class MypageViewModel
      {
       ObservableCollection<listItemLogicVM> lstvwItemSelected = new ObservableCollection<listItemLogicVM>()
          .
          -- OtherLogics
          .
      }
```

**listItemLogicVM**

```
    public class listItemLogicVM
     {
          public Command QtyDecrementCommand { get; set; }
           public int RequestingQty
             {
               get { return _requestingQty; }
               set { _requestingQty = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
             }
     }
```

Above Binding throws error. Can anyone help me to bind the command and property of **listItemLogicVM** to the list view in **MyPage XAML**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your listview XAML is incorrect. Try this (note the only changes are to the **x:Name** and **ItemsSource** attribute of your ListView):

```
<ListView x:Name="myUniqueListName" ItemsSource="{Binding 
     lstvwItemSelected}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                       <ViewCell >
                         <StackLayout>
                            <Entry Text="{Binding RequestingQty,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                             <Image Source="ArrowUp.png"><Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding QtyDecrementCommand}"/>
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                             </Image>
                         </StackLayout>
                       </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```

That should call the QtyDecrementCommand on the item that is tapped in the list. This assumes that you've correctly assigned some code to that command for each item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add command in your `MypageViewModel` and your xaml code look like :

```
<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference lstvwItemSelected}, Path=BindingContext.QtyDecrementCommand}"/>
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
```